# What can cause delayed onset CreateDialogIndirect() failure with GetLastError() == 0

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I am experiencing a really strange issue with an MFC C++ x86 application where dialogs that start to fail after a while. The application works fine for several hours after which some dialogs fail to open. There is no noticeable event or spike in activity that can reasonably explain why the failures start to appear. This issue affects many (but not all) dialogs with varying complexity ranging from a simple logon dialog to complex business dialogs with many complex controls. The dialogs that do work also vary in complexity. There is no obvious differences between dialogs that work and ones that fail.

When I place a breakpoint on AfxWndProc (inside wincore.cpp) and only activate it after entering CreateDialogIndirect(), It is hit as follows:

The good behaviour (first few hours before it breaks):
WM_NCCREATE (0x0081) - Returns 1
WM_NCCALCSIZE (0x0083) - Returns 0
WM_CREATE (0x0001) - Returns 0
WM_SIZE (0x0005) - Returns 0
WM_MOVE (0x0003) - Returns 0
WM_SETFONT (0x0030) - Returns 0
WM_INITDIALOG (0x0110) - Returns 1

After this there are a flurry of other messages (probably related to individual controls being initialised) before CreateDialogIndirect() eventually returns with a valid hWnd and GetLastError() returns 0

Once it goes into the bad state:
WM_NCCREATE (0x0081) - Returns 1
WM_NCCALCSIZE (0x0083) - Returns 0
WM_CREATE (0x0001) - Returns 0
WM_SIZE (0x0005) - Returns 0
WM_MOVE (0x0003) - Returns 0
WM_SETFONT (0x0030) - Returns 0
WM_UAHDESTROYWINDOW (0x0090) - Returns 0
WM_DESTROY (0x0002) - Returns 0
WM_NCDESTROY (0x0082) - Returns 0
CreateDialogIndirect() returns null and GetLastError() returns 0

I have investigated the following potential causes:

- GDI Handles: This seems to be low (less than 600)
- Invalid / bad control: All dialogs work initially so it is unlikely to be due to a custom control or dialog template
- Classes getting unregistered: I tried breakpoints inside MFC UnregiserClass calls. They are only triggered on application exit.

Some additional background information that might be relevant (or not):

- This is a win32 MFC x86 Dynamically linked application.
- The application is fairly complex (i.e. 50+ dialogs, Complex grid controls, Background streaming of incoming data, Multiple modules - each in its own DLL, Dynamic loading of language resources DLLs).
- The original codebase has been upgraded through multiple versions of MSVC (from 2005 to 2019)
- We encountered the issue on an instance built with VS2013 but have since upgraded the project to VS2019 (VC16) with no luck
- We have other clients running essentially the same codebase (different branch) built using VS2013 and they do not experience the issue.
- The issue can be seen on both Win7 and Win10

Any other clues or potential avenues of investigation will be appreciated.

**Edit:** We have since disovered that only dialogs containing Text Edit (CEdit) controls fail and that it appears to be due to memory even though the application memory is relatively low.

Comment: Probably you leak resources. GDI handles perhaps. No indication that GetLastError is meaningful after calling CreateDialogIndirect, which incidentally doesn't return any value.

Comment: @dav: Unfortunately, the documentation is wrong. Ever since moving to learn.microsoft.com, the C++ documentation is limited to express whatever the .NET CLR is capable of expressing. Preprocessor macros are unfortunately victims of this; they all list a return type of `void`. `CreateDialogIndirect[A|W]`, however, returns whatever [`CreateDialogIndirectParam[A|W]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createdialogindirectparamw) returns, an `HWND`. It also sets the last error code in case of failure.